# Search form is not displayed

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I tried to create a sample search form from railsCast #37:
railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form

And my text field looks invisible or hidden. Here is my code:

View:

```
<div>
<% form_tag 'mainbase', :method => 'get' do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
 @students = Student.search(params[:search])
```

Model:

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    where(['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
  else
    all
  end
end
```

Comment: Try adding the closing div element **</div>** to the end of the html

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing equal sign.

```
<%= form_tag 'mainbase', :method => 'get' do %>
```